# Getting bytes array from toolkit:AvatarView ImageSource property

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a picture in a `toolkit:AvatarView`. I need to retrieve the bytes array but I cannot do that.

What I did was the following:

```
            var picture = await ConvertImageSourceToStreamAsync(myPicture.ImageSource);

            using MemoryStream ms = new ();
            await picture.CopyToAsync(ms);
```

where `ConvertImageSourceToStreamAsync` is:

```
public async Task<Stream> ConvertImageSourceToStreamAsync(ImageSource imageSource)
{
    using var stream = await ((StreamImageSource)imageSource).Stream(CancellationToken.None);
    return stream;
}
```

The application hangs at `await picture.CopyToAsync(ms);` because the stream is closed.

What is the proper way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the ImageSource in the first place?

Comment: from a stream: `myPicture.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => item.Stream);`

Comment: And `item.Stream` comes from `FileResult.OpenReadAsync` , which, in turn, comes from `await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync()`

Comment: Then why do you need it back from the AvatarView if you have the original image?

Comment: Because I need to send the image through Internet and store it in the cloud.

Comment: then get the data from the original source